# Password Generating program in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, passwords, new-operator, solution

I have generated random passwords. Now i want to assign each password to each/different users present in the users list. but only the last password is being assigned to each user. The code is below.

```
import random

chars="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456!@#$%^&*()"
users=['A','B','C']


users_count= 0
for i in users: 
      users_count = users_count + 1
# print (str(users_count))



pass_len=int(input("Password length = "))
pass_count=users_count

for i in range(0,pass_count):
    password=""
    for i in range(0,pass_len):
        pass_chars= random.choice(chars)
        password=password+pass_chars 
    print("all pass are : " ,password)
 
for user in users:
    print(user," Password : ",password)
```

The output is like this:

```
Password length = 5
all pass are :  As6iI
all pass are :  FhAIX
all pass are :  fjJBH
A  Password :  fjJBH
B  Password :  fjJBH
C  Password :  fjJBH
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary to store the pairs <user, password>.

```
user_passwords = {}
for user in users: # For each user
    password = ""
    for i in range(0, pass_len): # Lets generate the password
        password = password + random.choice(chars) # Add a random character
    user_passwords[user] = password # assign the password to the user

for user in users:
    print(user," Password : ",user_passwords[user])
```

or a shorter version:

```
user_passwords = {}
for user in users:
    for i in range(0, pass_len):
        user_passwords[user] = user_passwords.get(user, "") + random.choice(chars)

for user in users:
    print(user," Password : ",user_passwords[user])
```

The problem with your code:

```
password=""
for i in range(0,pass_len):
    pass_chars= random.choice(chars)
    password=password+pass_chars 
print("all pass are : " ,password) 
        #   <-- Missing assigning the password to the user
```

was that you were generating random passwords but not assigning them to the users.

> but only the last password is being assigned to each user. The code is
> below.

That is because you were iterating over the users, by print always the last password that were generated previously:

```
for user in users:
    print(user," Password : ",password)
```

Answer (score 1):

'password' is a variable that can only have 1 value at a time, when you change the value of password in a loop, when the loop ends, only the last value will remain.

Create an array and append the passwords to it in a loop, then call the array in a loop for each user.